# Django Sass Compile on model save

Tags: python, css, django, sass

I'm making a django website with some products. Now I want to be able to customize some things from the admin. Like the background image and some primary and secundairy colors.

How I see this : I have a class SiteAppearance with an imagefield and a charfield for a color. When I save the model I generate the a small scss file with the def of $prim_color and $hero_bg ... This file is included in my general scss file.

So after this file is made and saved I want to re-compile this sass file so I get a new css file.

Any idea how i can compile the sass file from inside my save function?